# Use variable as filename for UNLOAD SQL

Tags: sql, odbc, sybase

I try to use a variable in a query to export with UNLOAD to a given filename using sybase.

```
BEGIN
declare DBNAME varchar(255);
set DBNAME = (select db_name());


UNLOAD SELECT identifiant,
identifiant AS id_pat,
null AS id_sec,
null as id_pr,
id_localite AS id_loc,
id_assure AS id_pat_ass,
id_civilite AS id_civ,
null AS id_cg,
id_mutuelle AS id_mut
FROM patient TO 'C:\\TPA\\export\\'+DBNAME+'.csv';

END;
```

I get Error near '+'
SQLCODE=-131

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Error is occurring on the line `FROM patient TO 'C:\\TPA\\export\\'+DBNAME+'.csv';`?  What happens when you use `'C:\\TPA\\export\\TEST.csv'` Does it work or any issues?

Comment: If I write a static path, it does work yes

Comment: sorry that seems like valid code and should work though.  Did you figure it out?